# Finding an injective function between an infinite set $A$ and the complement of $B$ in A, where B is a finite subset of A.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Basically if $C=A-B$, I want to find a one-to-one correspondence $f:A\rightarrow C$ where A is an infinite set and $B\subset A$ is finite. I thought of something like
$$f=
\begin{cases}
i(a), \; &a\in C,\\
??,\; &a\notin C
\end{cases}
$$
where $i$ is the identity $i:A\rightarrow A$. But I am not sure what I should replace the questionmarks with, or if it is even possible to construct like this. Could it be possible to replace the with a so called "empty function"? Help appreciated!

Comment: If $f$ is to be one-to-one, you can't define like that for $a \in C$ since you run out of elements of $C$ to map other elements of $A$ to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "Hilbert's hotel". Namely, first assume $A$ is countable, so without loss of generality let $B$ be the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dotsc, k\},$ and map $i$ to $i+k.$ Now, if $A$ is not countable, let $A = A_1 \cup A_2,$ where $A_1$ is countable, and the union is disjoint. Construct your map to be the Hilbert Hotel map on $A_1 \to A_1 \backslash C$ and the identity map elsewhere.

Comment: I feel dumb for asking but does this mean that in the countable case, that I would replace my question marks with the Hilbert Hotel map. Why is this injective?

Comment: Which two elements go to the same element?

Comment: If $A$ is for example the positive integers $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6.,..\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ then $C=\{4,5,6,...\}$, then in my construction every element $a\in A, a> 3$ would be maped to itself. But where would be $B=\{1,2,3\}$ be maped? From my understanding of the Hilbert Hotel map is that they would maped to $\{ 4,5,6\}$ and we don't have an injective function because $1$ is maped to $4$ and $4$ is maped to $4$ etc. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bigggie No. $4$ is mapped to $7$, $5$ to $8$, $6$ to $9$, then $7$ to $10$, and so on, as in the answer, $i$ to $i+k$, where $k=3$ in your example in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It’s definitely possible. Use the fact that every infinite set has a countable subset  and the fact there bijection from $R\cup
B\to R$ for any countable
$R$.